# Cannot add custom matchers for Jasmine using typescript and angular

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to add multiple new custom matchers to jasmine and use it, the goal is to create a file that register 2 matchers and all that matchers must be available for each test file with a single registration.

so i've got a file named `custom-matchers.ts`

```
/// <reference path="custom-matchers.d.ts"/>

(() => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toHaveText: () => {
        return {
          compare: (actual, expected) => {
            return {
              pass: actual.getText().then(pass => pass === expected)
            };
          },
        };
      },
      toBePresent: () => {
        return {
          compare: (actual, expected) => {
            return {
              pass: actual.isPresent().then(pass => pass === expected),
            };
          },
        };
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

A type definition file named `custom-matchers.d.ts` (i've tried with a different name than the references file but it's the same):

```
declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers<T> {
    toHaveText(text: any): boolean;
    toBePresent(text: any): boolean;
  }
}
```

this file is registered in another file named e2e-helper, this file is imported in every test file `e2e-helper.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="custom-matchers.d.ts"/>
import './custom-matchers';
```

When i try to use it in a test file for exemple:

```
expect(object as any).toBePresent();
```

I got an error :

> Property 'toBePresent' does not exist on type 'Matchers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, i just import my definition file in the helper file below the `custom-matchers.ts` file and rename it to have a different name import, so i have :

```
import './custom-matchers';
import './custom-matchers-types'; // definition file
```