# WebStorm doesn't recognize or autocomplete types declared globally in d.ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, webstorm, .d.ts

I'm trying to extend Jest's expect method per their [documentation here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers). I'm using TypeScript in a create-react-app project, so I need to extend the `CustomMatchers` interface to include my new expectation. That documentation has an example of how to do that.

I've put the type declaration in a `d.ts` file, and called `expect.extend` in my `setupTests.ts` script that runs before all the tests. When the test using the new expectation runs, it passes and fails correctly.

The problem is that WebStorm doesn't recognize the new expectation method. It underlines it in red saying `TS2339: Property 'toBeFocused' does not exist on type 'Matchers '`, and it won't autocomplete the name for me. I've tried putting the declaration in a file called `global.d.ts` or `jest.d.ts` in several different places in my project structure including `<root>`, `<root>/src`, `<root>/test`, and `<root>/typings`.

I've also tried including the `d.ts` file in the `.tsconfig`'s `include` array, and in `package.json`'s `types` array.

The **only** thing that works is including the type declaration and the call to `expect.extend` directly in a test file that uses the new expectation method.

I tried setting something up based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186602/3002766). The method wanted to add was called `toBeFocused`. A file called `matchers.ts` existed in `<root>/test` trying to declare the function, and `setupTests.ts` called `expect.extend`.

Comment: By the way, I know that there is a matcher called `toHaveFocus`. This is just an example I thought was easy to understand.

Comment: I used to link to a branch of a project showing this, but at some point I deleted the branch and now I don't have a reproducible example. Sorry about that.